# What is to be considered the "natural alignment" for OpCodes.Ldobj?

Tags: c#, alignment, cil, opcode

I am playing around with "Reflection.Emit" and want to generate a static class that exposes a method  with this signature in C#:

```
unsafe static void CopyStruct<T>(void * dest, ref T src) where T : struct
{
    // copy struct from src to dest using ldobj/stobj
}
```

This is in order to be able to **very** quickly (and unsafely) copy blittable structs to unmanaged memory. However, I ran in to some questions regarding *OpCodes.Ldobj* and *alignment*.

With the following two structs and methods:

```
struct Def { byte fill0; Int64 fill1; }            // size = 16
static void CopyDef(ref Def dest, ref Def src) { dest = src; }

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]    // size = 9
struct Seq { byte fill0; Int64 fill1; }
static void CopySeq(ref Seq dest, ref Seq src) { dest = src; }
```

I would expect the methods to generate something like this:

```
{ // CopyDef
  ldarg.0
  ldarg.1
  ldobj      Def
  stobj      Def
  ret
}
{ // CopySeq
  ldarg.0
  ldarg.1
  unaligned. 1
  ldobj      Seq
  unaligned. 1
  stobj      Seq
  ret
}
```

Instead I get the same output for *Seq* as I do for *Def*, i.e. no *unaligned x* opcode anywhere. I expected ldobj/stobj to treat anything other than the natural machine alignment (e.g. 8/4) as unaligned, but I'm clearly mistaken.

**My question with a followup:**

Is "Pack = 1" somehow implicitly "taken care of" due to the fact that the ldobj/stobj opcodes must specify the type of the address which they are operating on?

If this is the case, does that mean a struct with "Pack = 4" is implicitly "taken care of" so long as the address does not refer to an offset lower than 4 (e.g. 2,1), in which case the opcode must be preceded by *unaligned x*? This would of course only occur with an unmanaged pointer as in the initial method signature.

**Update:**

From *OpCodes.Ldind_I4* MSDN (1):

> All of the ldind instructions are shortcuts for a Ldobj instruction that specifies the corresponding built-in value class.

From *OpCodes.Unaligned* MSDN (2):

> Unaligned specifies that the address ... on the stack might not be aligned to the natural size of the immediately following ldind, stind, ... ldobj, stobj ... instruction. That is, for a Ldind_I4 instruction the alignment of the address may not be to a 4-byte boundary.

From *OpCodes.Ldobj* MSDN (3):

> The number of bytes copied depends on the size of the class (as specified by the class parameter). The class parameter is a metadata token representing the value type.

From *OpCodes.Ldind_I4* MSDN (4):

> The results of *all* MSIL instructions that return addresses (for example, Ldloca and Ldarga) are safely aligned.

This *suggests* that:

1. "Ldind_I4" == "Ldobj Int32"
2. Ldobj on a *4 byte* int considers a *4 byte* offset to be aligned.
3. Ldobj is "aware" of the size of the type it operates on.
4. Ldelema cannot produce a unaligned address.

The worst (lowest) possible offset within an array of any blittable struct is:

```
int offset = sizeof(myStruct) & 7; // 3 for 32bit
// offset == 0     -> correct
// offset == 1,3,7 -> unaligned. 1
// offset == 2,6   -> unaligned. 2
// offset == 4     -> unaligned. 4
```

The size of *Seq* is 9 which gives us an offset of 7, which means we are (worst case) unaligned by 1.

The following CopySeq method generates no unaligned opcode

```
static void CopySeq(ref Seq dest, Seq[] src) { dest = src[1]; }

{ // CopySeq
    ldarg.0
    ldarg.1
    ldc.i4.1
    ldelema    Seq
    ldobj      Seq
    stobj      Seq
    ret
}
```

Unless ldelema does some magic to the succeeding ldobj, then ldobj *ought* to known how to handle any misalignment that is possible to occur in an array of the specified type, as can be determined by the size of that type.

Comment: The struct is not misaligned.  That a field inside the struct might be misaligned plays no role.

Comment: @HansPassant what about a struct being in an array at seqArr[1], would it not be misaligned since sizeof(Seq) is 9 and the second item would come directly after?

Comment: You don't use ldobj to load array elements directly, you use ldelema.

Comment: @HansPassant I know about ldelema. What I'm saying is that a caller of CopySeq could pass two items from two arbirtrary indices of a seqArr[]. Either of those items _could_ be misaligned, with different offsets even. Is this not true?